# usage of "curriculum"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular, redundancy, implication

If curriculum already implies academic, is it redundant to say I have equipped myself with a diverse **academic** curriculum? Also, is curriculum plural (is "**a** curriculum" appropriate)?

Comment: "is it redundant to say I have equipped myself with a diverse academic curriculum?" - rather than redundant, I would say it was poor English.

Answer (score 1):

Curriculum doesn't imply the academic. [Curriculum](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curriculum) refers to courses and subjects that are taught in academic institutions.

*Academic curriculum* is a correct phrase that means a curriculum relating to academic. However, it's advised to not use that phrase since it hasn't found its way on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=academic%20curriculum%2C%20curriculum&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cacademic%20curriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bacademic%20curriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAcademic%20Curriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAcademic%20curriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccurriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcurriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCurriculum%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCURRICULUM%3B%2Cc0)

Curriculum is singular and ***a*** curriculum is appropriate. The plural form for *curriculum* is *curriculums*

Comment: Note that curriculum has two accepted plural forms, like many Latin-derived nouns.  Both _curriculums_ and _curricula_ are acceptable and common.

Comment: "Relating to academic" doesn't sound to me like something a native English speaker would say. Nor does "It's advised to not use".